# Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_and ID AWS_ACCESS_KEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, google-kubernetes-engine

I have spring boot webapp to deploy in GKE and database is on AWS aurora db.
Then I need inside my manifest I use 'aws-iam-token'.
This is my Deployment:

```
#Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: drms-pd-myapp
  namespace: drmspd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drms-pd-myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: drms-pd-myapp
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: sa-dev
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: registry-secret
      volumes:
        - name: aws-iam-token
          projected:
            defaultMode: 420
            sources:
              - serviceAccountToken:
                  audience: sts.amazonaws.com
                  expirationSeconds: 86400
                  path: token
        - name: pdrms-myapp-cfgmap
          configMap:
            name: pdrms-myapp-cfgmap
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: TZ
          value: Europe/Rome
        - name: AWS_ROLE_ARN
          value: arn:aws:iam::888070426710:role/.........
        - name: AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
          value: /var/run/secrets/aws-iam-token/serviceaccount/token
        - name: AWS_REGION
          value: eu-south-1
        image: myimage/drms_pd_myapp_cloud
        ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: drms-pd-myapp
        volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/aws-iam-token/serviceaccount
           name: aws-iam-token
           readOnly: true
         - mountPath: /deployments/config
           name: pdrms-myapp-cfgmap
           readOnly: true
```

Webapp is deployed successfully by GKE but goest into this error:

```
o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Failed to initialize pool: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@158e9f6e: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@4ef2ab73: Unauthorized (Service: null; Status Code: 401; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)]
```

I would like to know if serviceAccountToken should be responsible to populate these missing environment variables.

Thanx